# Azure Maps - maxbounds

Tags: azure-maps

I am trying to set the maxBounds so that a map cannot be panned outside of Los Angeles County.  When I set try to use the it in either of the following ways, it does not restrict the panning of the map as desired:

```
function GetMap(){
  //Instantiate a map object
    var map = new atlas.Map("myMap", {
        style: 'grayscale_light',
        center: [-118.25, 34.0],
        maxBounds: [-121, 31, -115, 37],
```

OR

```
    map.setCamera({
    maxBounds: [-121, 31, -115, 37],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both methods and they are both working correctly. Not that your bounding box values are much larger than Los Angeles County. The following is a much tighter bounding box around that area. [-118.851303, 32.721998, -117.659286, 34.831255]

Note that this will still show a lot of area outside of LA county since the county boundary is not square. For reference: https://www.bing.com/maps?q=Los+Angeles+County&FORM=HDRSC6

Comment: I tried it with the update coordinates and it still lets me pan and zoom out to the full extent  of the world map.  My intent is to restrict panning and max zoom out to LA County.

Comment: Is there code sample for maxBounds that demonstrates its ability to limit panning?

Comment: There wasn't, but I've just added one here: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?&sample=Limit%20map%20view%20with%20maxBounds

Comment: Thanks.  Realizing now that the problem I am experiencing likely relates to applying maxBounds when I also have the starting pitch set to 45.  I was able to make it work when I remove the pitch setting.  Is it possible to restrict the boundary with a pitch view?

Comment: You can, but the restriction will likely be based on the center of the map, rather than on the edge of the map canvas. Otherwise you will never get a good look at the locations near the edges.